# How to programmatically detect Mac OS X Server Edition?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is anybody knows any API that can help to distinguish Mac OS X "Server edition" from "Desktop edition"? 
My application should know on which edition of Mac OS X it currently running. (Server or Desktop)

Answer (score 6):

`sw_vers` appears to do it by checking /System/Library/CoreServices/ServerVersion.plist -- you could probably get by with just seeing if the file exists.

Comment: that’s actually what the very little in the way of Apple stuff which cares does, in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a real reason why your application needs to know this, I'd recommend checking for the existence of the component that makes the difference on desktop/server. For example, if the server version comes with the program or library `foo` and the desktop version doesn't, and you would like to use `foo`, then check for the existence (and/or version of) `foo` instead of trying to infer it from Server vs Desktop OS.

(Meanwhile, one possible starting point to check the OS version are the commands `sw_vers` and `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType`.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find a difference using the [sysctl API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/boundaries/boundaries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH217-BABJJBHG), or [Gestalt](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Gestalt_Manager/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I already checked this APIs, but Unfortunately I not found any suitable flags or parameters that will allow do this. (Gestalt have hundreds of flags and I failed to find the right one for this task)